# Array of credentials

Tags: arrays, pointers, credentials, access-violation, visual-c++-2008

I'm developing a credential provider and credential. So I have this class `SampleProvider` and `SampleCredential`. It works well when I specifically declare that `SampleProvider` has one, or two, or a constant number of `SampleCredential`, by declaring:

```
SampleCredential * _pCredential[2]
```

But now, I want it to be dynamically allocated. So I will have this:

```
SampleCredential * *_pCredential
```

And then inside the method `SetUsageScenario()`, the code will read the number of credentials from a txt file, and allocate it:

```
(*_pCredential) = new SampleCredential[numberCount];
```

But it is not working. I keep getting error on that line. It says

> Access violation writing location 0x00000000 ;

Do you know what happens here and what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_pCredential has probably not been initialized yet and is still NULL.  Attempting to dereference the null pointer via "(*_pCredential)" would then result in your access violation.

Maybe you meant to do this?

```
_pCredential = new SampleCredential*[numberCount];
```

That will allocate an array of pointers to SampleCredential objects.  You can then allocate each SampleCredential object like this:

```
_pCredential[0] = new SampleCredential();
// etc.
```

Remember to free the memory when you're done:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberCount; i++) {
    delete _pCredential[i];
}
delete [] _pCredential;
```